# A representation of a finite group where every nonzero vector has a trivial stabilizer

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

What are the finite groups which admit a non-zero representation in char 0 where every non-zero vector has stabilizer equal to $\left<1\right>$? Cyclic groups of prime order is one obvious class.  Is there anything else?

Comment: All nontrivial cyclic groups, ${\rm SL}(2,5)$ and its subgroups.

Comment: Also generalized quaternion groups.

Comment: A sylow $2$-subgroup would have to be cyclic or generalized quaternion, which restricts the structure. I wonder if there are any interesting odd order examples.

Comment: After reading Geoff Robinson's answer, I found the earlier post, which is http://mathoverflow.net/questions/191769 So perhaps this question should be regarded as a duplicate?

Comment: @Derek Holt: I agree that there is not much to be learned from this question which is not covered by the earlier question and its answers.

Comment: @Nico: As Derek (and Geoff) point out, this question is essentially contained in an older one.   Aside from that, it's helpful to make "in char 0" more precise, since one usually starts by working over an algebraically closed field such as $\mathbb{C}$ followed by comparisons with representations over arbitrary fields.

Answer (score 8):

I think these groups have appeared on MO before.  A finite group $H$ has such a representation in characteristic zero if and only if $H$ occurs as a Frobenius complement. This is "well-known folklore" and appears in a book by D. Passman for example.

First, if $H$ is Frobenius complement in a Frobenius group $G$ with Frobenius kernel $K$,
any non-trivial minimal $H$-invariant subgroup $V$ of $K$ is an elementary Abelian $q$-group for some prime $q$ not dividing $|H|$, since $|H|$ and $|K|$ are comprime. Also $H$ acts faithfully on $V$. We can pass to an algebraic closure of ${\rm GF}(q)$ and lift the representation of $H$ to characteristic zero, and we obtain a complex representation of $H$ such that all non-identity elements act without the eigenvalue $1$.

Conversely, if $H$ has a complex representation with this last property, then we can reduce the associated module (mod $q$) for some prime $q$ not dividing $|H|$. Then we easily obtain a semidirect product $VH$ with $V$ an elementary Abelian normal $q$-subgroup such that $H$ is a Frobenius complement.

The structure of a (finite) Frobenius complement $H$  is reasonably well understood. For example, Burnside knew that if $p$ and $q$ are different prime divisors of $H$, every subgroup of $H$ of order $pq$ is cyclic. As mentioned in comments, all Sylow subgroups of $H$ are cyclic or (generalized) quaternion.

The only perfect Frobenius complement is ${\rm SL}(2,5).$ There is a Frobenius complement of order $63$ with center of order $3$.

Later edit: This last group has a complex irreducible representation of degree $3$ in which no non-identity element has an eigenvalue $1$. In general, a Frobenius complement of odd order is metacyclic.

Even later edit: Here is a quick direct proof that any finite non-trivial group $G$ which has all subgroups normal necessarily has an irreducible complex representation (which may not be faithful) of the type in the question: take $\chi$ to be an irreducible non-trivial complex character of $G$. Let $N = {\rm ker} \chi$. Then by induction, we may suppose that $N = 1$, as $G/N$ has all its subgroups normal. Hence we may suppose that $\chi$ is faithful. For any $g \in G^{\#}
$, Clifford's theorem tells us that ${\rm Res}^{G}_{\langle g \rangle}(\chi)$ is a sum of $G$-conjugate irreducible characters of $\langle g \rangle$, since $\langle g \rangle \lhd G.$ None of these can be the trivial character (or they would all be trivial, since they are all $G$-conjugate, and that would put $g$ in ${\rm ker}\chi$). Hence $g$ acts without the eigenvalue $1$ in the representation affording $\chi$.

Comment: Is there a reference discussing that Frobenius complement of order 63, and its 3D representation you mention?

Comment: I am not sure about an explicit reference: the group is $\langle a, b : a^{7} = b^{9} = 1, b^{-1}ab = a^{2}  \rangle..$  There is a $3$-dimensional representation, where $a$ may be represented by $\left(\begin{array}{clcr} \omega & 0 & 0\\0&\omega^{2} & 0\\0&0&\omega^{4}\end{array} \right)$, ($\omega$ a primitive complex $7$-th root of unity) and $b$ may be represented by $\left( \begin{array}{clcr} 0&\alpha &0\\0&0&\alpha\\ \alpha & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right)$, where $\alpha$ is a primitive $9$-the root of unity.